# Open new View when new ViewModel is available?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am relatively new to WPF/MVVM. Our current WPF project is still a prototype application, which means we haven't come to designing of main layout. But we do have designed some reports (by reports, I mean some quite complicated `UserControl` each of which has some configuration controls such as `ComobBox`or `TextBox`, and some `DataGrid`, `Graph` controls for the data we want to present) as `View`and their `ViewModel`. It is still prototype, so we just need to open a new `Window` which displays any of these `UserControl`. In the future, we might change it to locate different `UserControl` in different regions inside the main window, like the layout of Visual Studio. The MAIN point is, our application would include almost a hundred of such `UserControl` or what we call reports. So it is different from my previous working projects which had static layout/MainView.

I still haven't figured out a good architecture for it. Our classic usage scenario is to let the user to select in the menu report to open, and so we have `Command` (either in MainViewModel, or in any ViewModel of report) objects to open a new report. So basically the `Command` is generating a new `ViewModel` (`ViewModel` first case) and then a corresponding `View` should be generated (by whom?), and finally a new `Window` should be opened including the newly-generated `UserControl`.

I guess I need two services:

1. a service which subscribes to the new-ViewModel-generated event, and resolve the `UserControl` when such event happens.
2. (for our current prototype application) a window manager, which subscribes to the new-UserControl-generated event published by the 1) service, and then opens a new Window to display it.

And in the future for our actual application, we can change the 2) service and put them into different regions. For the second, it is simple and only temporary, I can just have one object in the code-behind of MainView, which subscribes to the event using `EventAggregator`, and generate a new `Window`. Is it correct ?

Can somebody tell me how I should achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at MEF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx. It could act as 1st service (View can import ViewModel)

Comment: @amnezjak it might be that I don't understand it correctly. But my feeling is our app is more like a `ViewModel`-first one, for example, one `Command` object from one `ViewModel` gets executed and generate another different `ViewModel` and I need to resolve the `View` for it. But in your proposal, the `View` imports `ViewModel`. BTW, who is responsible to generate the `View` in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data binding can already handle this for you. In the container where you want to display the reports add a `ContentControl` and bind it to a property that holds the VM for the report that you want to display currently.

```
<Window>
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentReport}" />
</Window>
```

To display the different reports wrap each of the `UserControls` in its own `DataTemplate` that can be injected into the `ContentControl`. To actually resolve the view you have a few choices. You can create a `DataTemplateSelector` to map them or just specify the VM types on your templates. In either case, make sure the templates are in scope at the `ContentControl` (in `Resources` in the same file or a parent, or merged from standalone `ResourceDictionary`).

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:FirstReportViewModel}">
  <views:FirstReportViewControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do have one more question: since we have at least 100 of such reports/`UserControl`, is `DataTemplate` and `ReSources` a good choice for this scenario? And like I mentioned, although currently we display each report in individual window, we will change it in the actual application by setting some window and assign different reports in different regions. Is this `DataTemplate`  method generic so that we can achieve that?

Comment: Yes to both. You'll need to make sure to keep everything organized with that many templates but that's not unique to this solution. It's especially good for changing containers since the only thing you need to place a report is a single ContentControl element.

Answer (score 0):

John Bowen beat me to it, by I thought I'd still post, maybe it helps.

For associating views with view models you can use data templates in a resource dictionary.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AllCustomersViewModel}">
    <vw:AllCustomersView />
</DataTemplate>
```

As you probably already know, you can set namespaces within your resource dictionaries. In this example vw and vm reference the folders containing viewmodels and views respectively.
Now you can use content control to generate the views by binding to the view model.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeViewModel}" />
```

The code above has been shamelessly stolen from [Josh Smith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) btw.

So, you should not need a service for resolving the association of view to viewmodel. Let the framework do the work for you. 
I actually do not recommend opening new windows. If you must, using a "Window Controller"-Service of some sort will be unavoidable. However, I advise you to stick to a single window containing multiple viewmodels and exchanging them upon receiving certain events.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you kindly give me some example of such Window controller? Because our SW, like I have implied, includes hundreds of reports and multiple reports are normally opened at the same time. Our legacy SW is a MDI (Multiple Document Interface). Unless we can think of some different and proper layout, my feeling is in new WPF application we still want to follow such UI arrangement. For example, the main layout of Visual Studio (tabular controls with only one document showed at one time) is not desired

Comment: Also, I mentioned our current WPF app is only prototype and that's why we open different reports in individual windows. In the future we would like to use the `View` and `ViweModel` differently. So is the `DataTemplate` method a good way to be used in that scenario? My feeling is this methods is not flexible enough...